# Does python automatically get an alias in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So our team has a Dockerfile build (centos 8 operating system build) with the following line:

`dnf -y --setopt=install_weak_deps=False --best install python37`

1. Does "python37" automatically get aliased as "python" on the newly built image? Or if I ssh into the system built by the Dockerfile I have to do something like "python37 --version" to reference the python executable correctly?

There's no "alias" reference anywhere in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not aliased but linked via symbolic link(s). The easiest way is to check (I have python3.6 installed).

inside of container:

```
ls -l $(which python3)

# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Aug  6 19:29 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
```

The about output is another symbolic link so by following it:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/python3

# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug  6 19:29 /etc/alternatives/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6
```

So the answer is that by running `python3`, the `/usr/bin/python3.6` is being executed.

It you need to run python as `python` instead of `python3`, you can add this line which will link them.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: So I basically am running a script "python hello.py" on the container but it's complaining about not finding python. Does this mean I should symlink python to python37 when I build the Docker container via Dockerfile?

Comment: To `python3`. Not to `3.7`. But you can simply run `python3` instead of `python` which generally refers to python2 which you have not installed.

Comment: Updated the answer.